# extracting design information from customer images, iOS, png

Tags: ios

I have a client who wants me to build an iPhone app for him. He designed the UI himself and gave it to me in the form of PNG's. if anyone who has been through this kind of issue, what kind of tools do you use to get all the nitty gritty details of this design? 
I have sketch licensed already but just want to know whats a good way to dissect this information and figure all the dimensions of the buttons or navbar for example.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the designs would be made in Photoshop or equivalent, to scale, and the PNGs can be distributed as 'designs'.  You can then obtain the actual assets themselves, to-scale, from Photoshop by slicing them using the appropriate tools.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can say is to contact the client. They will know what they used, and if not, try using Photoshop as mentioned before. I would say in the editor, use the "select" tool (the dashed outline square icon) and see if you can get the dimensions off the selected tool. For example, select only the button or whatever, and then just right click, and see if there is a "get info" button, if not, there should be a section of the editor that deals with the image sizing.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Unless you client is a UXD or a graphics artist with experience of designing iOS applications, this is absolutely the worst kind of 'specification' to be given because it will failed to use interaction idioms of the platform, and may work very badly in practice.

Clearly the graphical elements you need for individual controls (chops) are probably not what you have been given, and furthermore, even on graphics heavy design, you are likely to be using standard controls with elements of their design.

From a point of view of development effort, a fully custom skinned design is exceptionally hard work, and best avoided.

Ideally, you want the layers your PNGs have been composited from, rather than the final PNG.  Most likely this was done in Photoshop, but needn't have been.   This is what will drive your choice of tools to use.